# Whenever I execute my code it gives me what looks like memory addresses and other nonesense

Tags: java, arrays

Whenever I execute my code in java with eclipse (code is as follows)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PracticeOne {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner scn = new Scanner (System.in);

    int first = scn.nextInt();
    scn.nextLine();

    for(int i =0; i<first; i++){
        String preSplt = scn.next();
        String postSplt[] = preSplt.split("--");
        System.out.println(postSplt);
    }
  }

}
```

and once I type in

```
3
Honda element--19--17950 
Ford Edge--19--18130
```

it gives me this

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@c0fa1f5
[Ljava.lang.String;@4e15f6af
```

in between "Honda element" and "Ford Edge" as I press enter and then it spits out

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@3f68336
```

after "Ford Edge" and for the record it does not split the input I give it or do anything after it spits out that last bit although this may be due to ineffective code (I am not done with this program yet) I thought it might be a little helpful

I find assembly language quite fascinating but I would like to know whats causing this and if it even has anything to do with assembly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you're attempting to print the array object itself instead of its contents.  Use [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(postSplt));
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip it is working fine now! I can't believe I forgot such a simple thing!!